# Auto incremental DataGrid column without adding it to the DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my `DataGrid` there's a Serial column, its only job is to show the order number beside the record, so if there are 10 records then the column holds numbers from 1 to 10 .. to achieve this I'm adding a new property especially for that case in a partial class and in the code I loop through the list incrementing the `Serial` property for each loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lstPriceListItems.Count; i++)
    {
       lstPriceListItems[i].Serial = i + 1;
    }
```

then in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial" Binding="{Binding Serial}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I beleive that this is not practical, because the `lstPriceListItems` represent a data object while `Serial` is UI feature represented as a number, they must not be combined together, so I thought if there is a way in XAML handling such scenario without touching the DataContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach really. `lstPriceListItems` may be seen as a *view* model since it is being displayed in a `DataGrid`.

If you are using this class somewhere else outside of your client application, you could create a new class that wraps it and adds the additional `Serial` property and set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a sequence of the new type and populate the `Serial` property like you are currently doing.

Another approach would be to handle the `LoadingRow` event for the `DataGrid` as suggested here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/08/18/right-aligned-row-numbers-datagridrowheader-wpf/. Or bind using a converter that displays the 1-based index of the current item.

Comment: could you please explain the suggestion of using converter?

Comment: Read the blog post.

Comment: I read the part of using the LoadingRow event, which works in the DataGrid but not in the Syncfusion SfDataGrid (I didn't mention for simplicity)..
I'll read the full post then. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very simple way you could do this with XAML and the code behind without actually touching the DataContext. You need to add an event called LoadingRow. Whenever a new row is added on the DataGrid or the whole dataGrid is loaded it will actually auto increment.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridName" LoadingRow="DataGridName_LoadingRow">
   <DataGridColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
   </DataGridColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

then in the code behind do this

```
private void DataGridName_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }
```